# How to create a div with this format with CSS

Tags: html, css, format

I need to create a `div` with this format from the attached image, could someone help? Does anyone know how I can do this using only **CSS**

[image]

Comment: Maybe overlapping div with `border-radius` could do it but I would use SVG code.

Comment: @Jax-p `clip-path: ellipse` would be easier.

Comment: @tacoshy Nice one. Yes, as long as you [do not need to support IE 11](https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path).

Comment: @Jax-p techincally correct howeever IE11 has already been started to be deprecated by Microsoft itself at the 16th August 2021. Until March 2022 it will be completely deprecated for all windows and offcie versions. Specifically supporting a deprecated browser is technically "wasted efford". Thats also the reason why IE11 does not support so many W3 standards as microsoft didnt put any efford in updating something that they wanted to deprecate in the first place.